# How to enable editText on touch

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an editText which is disabled and I want to enable it when I touch it.

Here is what I've done but it doesn't work :

```
if(textmail.isEnabled() == false){
        textmail.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                textmail.setEnabled(true);
                return true;
            }


        });
    }
```

Comment: What is problem you are facing??

Comment: you are returning false that's why it is not getting enabled ..return true;

Comment: @Anmol the editText is not enabling it only work when the editText is already enabled

Comment: @AnushaMathur even with true nothing change

Comment: try my answer the if condition should be inside `onTouch() `
@Amal

Comment: If the view is disabled it does not trigger OnTouchListener(), because it is **disabled**.

Comment: I think you need to make a customView that calls `onTouch` even when it's disabled.

Comment: @forpas yes you are right have you any propose for that, thank you

Comment: how to do that @SamzSakerz

Comment: Put the view inside a layout and set the listener to the layout. I haven't tried it, it's just an idea.

Comment: @Amal can you please elaborate what functionality you want..so we can help you in better way.

Comment: Well. Why are you disabling the EditText in the first place? what's the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **disable** the Edittext, it will not trigger the events i.e. **onTouch/onClick**. In order to tackle this issue, you need to avoid using disable and use clickable instead. `textmail.setClickable(false);` within your onCreate method.

To make the component look like it has been disabled, you can also work with the Alpha value where you are to reduce the opacity of the component to make it look faded away.

```
textmail.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

Now it should response to your listener...

```
textmail.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        textmail.setClickable(true);
        textmail.setAlpha(1f);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Amal glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

i read your use-case carefully you want to disable your TextView and want to disable it onTouch() (*Correct me if i am wrong*)

Here's a solution instead of using `setEnabled()` as if you set it `onTouch()` is not called so better to do it manually by declaring a global variable(boolean) in  your (View/activity/fragment/class) where you are writing the logic.

```
    //this as global variable
    private boolean isTextViewDisabled=false;


    //place this code on onCreate()
    textmail.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ){
             if(isTextViewDisabled){
               return false;
              }
            }
          return true;
        }
    });
```

Set your isTextViewDisabled to `true` and `false` when needed as per your use-case.

But confusion here is condition for enabling and disabling should be something else not the `touch event` as according to your use case code should be like below:

```
   //place this code on onCreate()
    textmail.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ){
             if(isTextViewDisabled){
               isTextViewDisabled=false;
              }
            }
          return true;
        }
    });
```

The above code doesn't make a lot of sense until you explain why you want to disable the textView

Comment: check @Amal now

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope this help

```
        textmail.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {



       if(textmail.isEnabled() == false){
                textmail.setEnabled(true);
            }  
                return true;
            }


        });
```